# How to access variable in a global class not in app_code in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

I have a global class which is not in `app_code` folder. I have declared a static variable in that class. However since it is not in `app_code` folder I am not able to access it from another web page. Can anyone help me to access it's contents?

Comment: post your code, class location doesn't matter

Comment: i have a code if (GlobalClass._stuid != null && GlobalClass._stuid != 0)
            { } but in this code getting error GlobalClass doesn't exist in current content

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Where that class is located currently? have you included the namespace Properly?

Comment: it is in the directory of my webapplication

Answer (score 0):

You can access using **System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(YourClass);**

```
   using System;

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
      public class Global : System.Attribute
       {
        public string Url;

        public Global(string url)   // url is a positional parameter
        {
        this.Url = url;
        }

      }
       [HelpAttribute("Information on the class MyClass")]
        class YourClass
       {
       }


   namespace AttributeAppl
  {
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(MyClass);
     object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);

      Global dbi = (Global )Url;
    }
  }
}
```